# Como posso exibir como string qualquer objeto JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

Se eu tenho um objeto qualquer como `new MeuObjeto()`, e quero exibir como string todas as suas propriedades internas. Como posso fazer isso?

Quando uso `alert(new MeuObjeto())` o resultado é `[object Object]`. Mas quero o conteúdo do objeto como texto, `string`.

```
var MeuObjeto = function() {
    this.prop1 = "Olá, Mundo!";
    this.prop2 = "Hahahaha";
    this.recursivo = this;
    this.funcao = function() { return "retorno da função"; }
}
alert(new MeuObjeto());
```

Neste caso quero que seja exibido no `alert()` algo como `{ prop1 = "Olá, Mundo!", prop2 = "Hahahaha", etc... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode escrever esta função para **converter qualquer objeto** para `string`.

Veja este [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aj3Lv2hs/5/) de exemplo da função abaixo

```
function ToString(obj) {
    clearTimeout(window.ToStringTimeout);

    var result;
    var ident = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : undefined;

    if (obj == null) {
        result = String(obj);
    }

    var objString;
    try {
        objString = obj.toString();
    } catch (err1) {
        try {
            objString = String(obj); 
        } catch (err2) {
            try {
                objString = obj + "";
            } catch (err3) {
                objString = "ERROR CONVERT STRING";
            }
        }
    }

    if (!result) {
        window.ToStringRecursive = window.ToStringRecursive ? window.ToStringRecursive : [];
        if (window.ToStringRecursive.indexOf(obj) >= 0) {
            result = obj ? (typeof(obj) == "string" ? "\"" + obj + "\"" : objString) : obj;
        } else {
            window.ToStringRecursive.push(obj);
        }
        if (!result) {
            switch (typeof obj) {
                case "string":
                    result = '"' + obj + '"';
                    break;
                case "function":
                    result = obj.name || objString;
                    break;
                case "object":
                    var indent = Array(ident || 1).join('\t'),
                        isArray = Array.isArray(obj);
                    result = '{[' [+isArray] + Object.keys(obj).map(
                        function(key) {
                            return '\n\t' + indent + key + ': ' + ToString(obj[key], (ident || 1) + 1);
                        }).join(',') + '\n' + indent + '}]' [+isArray];
                    break;
                default:
                    result = objString;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    window.ToStringTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        delete window.ToStringTimeout;
        delete window.ToStringRecursive;
    }, 100);

    return result;
}
```

Teste usando isso:

```
console.log(ToString(new MyObject()));
```

Para exibir isso:

```
{
    prop1: "Olá, Mundo!",
    prop2: "Hahahaha",
    recursivo: [object Object],
    funcao: function () { return "retorno da função"; }
}
```

Veja que quando uma propriedade é recursiva ela não exibida novamente porque daria um loop infinito.

EDIT1: Para funcionar no NodeJS declare `var window = { };`

Comment: Não tem como mexer o vetor, é melhor fazer manual, o caso sistema vetor tem padrão. Entenda sobre "Estrutura de vetores e matrizes (Programação)" e tbm veja sobre POO (Programação Orientada a Objetos)

Answer (score 5):

Acho que podes fazer isso assim:

```
function stringify(algo) {
    function checktype(obj) {
        if (!obj || typeof obj == 'number' || typeof obj == 'string') return obj;
        if (typeof obj == 'function') return obj.toString();
        var _obj = Array.isArray(obj) ? [] : {};
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
            if (obj[key] == obj) _obj[key] = 'instance of itself';
            else _obj[key] = checktype(obj[key]);
        });
        return _obj;
    };
    return JSON.stringify(checktype(algo), '\t', 4);
};
```

Criei uma proteção para referências circulares com

```
if (obj[key] == obj) _obj[key] = 'instance of itself';
```

outra opção seria limitar a profundidade do objeto.

Funciona para o teu exemplo, em casos mais complexos pode precisar de ser afinado.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uL3mt94n/

Comment: Dessa forma você modifica o objeto, é isso?

Comment: @SergioCabral não. Eu crio uma variável temporária `_obj` e não mexo em nada de `obj`.

Answer (score 2):

Para imprimir um Objeto, você pode serializar ele primeiro usando o [`JSON.strigify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), mas este pode vir a se tornar uma dor de cabeça caso tenha alguma referencia circular no seu objeto.

E como não existe uma normalização de como lidar com elas no objeto, então cada biblioteca lida com ela de uma forma diferente, por exemplo o [`Json.NET - Newtonsoft`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) no C# lida de uma forma, já no `JavaScript` à implementação do [`JSON`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) feita pelo `Douglas Crockford` lida de outra.

No geral eles usam como base à definição usada pelo [`JSON Schema`](http://json-schema.org/example2.html) para montar um `schema` para o `JSON`, porém com alguma pequenas diferenças (e nesta diferença onde mora o perigo, e como resultado acaba sendo um inferno enviar este objeto por AJAX para qual quer lugar).

Abaixo segue um exemplo usando a biblioteca do `Douglas Crockford` para resolver o problema da referencia circular o `JSON.strigify` para imprimir ela.

```js
var MeuObjeto = function() {
    this.prop1 = "Olá, Mundo!";
    this.prop2 = "Hahahaha";
    this.recursivo = this;
    this.funcao = function() { return "retorno da função"; }
}

var obj = new MeuObjeto();

obj = JSON.decycle(obj);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

obj = JSON.retrocycle(obj);
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/cycle.js"></script>
```

E por fim, você pode notar que o `Snippet` do `StackOverFlow` já usa uma abordagem diferente para resolver o problema da referencia circular.